# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch on Python

Tags: python, heroku

I have developed VK bot on language python and deploy to Heroku 
after the command heroku ps:scale web=1, the script runs and works few seconds and after few seconds script stops proccess with log

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within
>   60 seconds of launch on Python Process exited with status 137

That is my Procfile: 
**web: python bot.py**

I changed the Procfile to: **web: python bot.py -p $PORT**, but It did not help

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200946/error-r10-boot-timeout-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-90-second).